# Is it bad practice to return an iterable in a method?

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I have often read in many places that one should avoid returning an `iterable` and return a `collection` instead. For example -

```
public Iterable<Maze> Portals() {     
    // a list of some maze configurations
    List<Maze> mazes = createMazes();
    ...
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(mazes);
}
```

Since returning an `iterable` is only useful for using it in `foreach` loop, while `collection` already provides an `iterator` and provides much more control. Could you please tell me when it is beneficial to specifically return an `iterable` in a method? Or we should always return a `collection` instead?

Note : This question is not about Guava library

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Returning an `Iterable` would be beneficial when we need to lazily load a collection that contains a lot of elements.

The following quote from [Google Collections FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/google-collections/wiki/Faq) seems to support the idea of lazy loading:

> Why so much emphasis on Iterators and Iterables?
>
> In general, our methods do not require a Collection to be passed in
>   when an Iterable or Iterator would suffice. This distinction is
>   important to us, as sometimes at Google we work with very large
>   quantities of data, which may be too large to fit in memory, but which
>   can be traversed from beginning to end in the course of some
>   computation. Such data structures can be implemented as collections,
>   but most of their methods would have to either throw an exception,
>   return a wrong answer, or perform abysmally. For these situations,
>   Collection is a very poor fit; a square peg in a round hole.
>
> An Iterator represents a one-way scrollable "stream" of elements, and
>   an Iterable is anything which can spawn independent iterators. A
>   Collection is much, much more than this, so we only require it when we
>   need to.

Answer (score 2):

I can see advantages and disadvantages:

- One advantage is that `Iterable` is a simpler interface than `Collection`.  If you have a non-standard collection type, it may be easier to make it `Iterable` than `Collection`.  Indeed, there are some kinds of collection for which some of the `Collection` methods are problematic to implement.  For example, lazy collections types and collections where you don't want to rely on the standard `equals(Object)` method to determine membership.
- One disadvantage is that `Iterable` is functionality poor.  If you have a concrete type that implements `Collection`, and you return it as an `Iterable`, you are removing the possibility that the code can (directly) call a variety of useful collection methods.
- There are some cases where neither Iterable or Collection are a good fit; e.g. specialist collections of primitive types ... where you need to avoid the overheads of using the primitive wrapper types.

You can't really say whether it is good or bad practice to return an `Iterable`.  It depends on the circumstances; e.g. the purpose of the API you are designing, and the requirements or constraints that you want / need to place on it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if underlying collection changes, you will be in trouble.
If you are using a collection which throws `concurrentmodification` exception then you have to take care of it as well but with collection there are no such issues.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  The underlying collection is still the same implementation, regardless of whether it's being held in an `Iterable` or a `Collection` reference.

Comment: @SimonC: Take the scenario where i return an iterable to a user and he starts to iterate the collection using it and while he is iterating the some other user changes the collection. User will get exception right. Does it make sense now ?

Comment: I know what you're trying to say, but exactly the same thing will happen if the collection that is being modified is being held in a variable typed as `Iterable` as a variable typed as `Collection`.  The collection being modified is still the same concrete type.

Comment: @SimonC: My point is if you have collection with you then you always have option of traversing without using iterator and hence can avoid concurrentmodification exception. If you are passing iterator then you  have no choice.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now.  However, `ConcurrentModificationException`s indicate a programming error.  You should not be intentionally accessing a collection that you know may be modified by another thread without some sort of synchronisation.  Using the methods on `Collection` to access a collection being modified by another thread may avoid an exception being thrown, but will have unpredictable behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Return the most specific type that makes sense for the use in question. If you have a method that's creating a new collection, for example, or you can easily wrap the collection in an unmodifiable wrapper, returning the collection as a `Collection`, or even a `List` or `Set`, makes the client developer's life a little easier.

Returning `Iterable` makes sense for code where the values may be generated on-the-fly; you could imagine a Fibonacci generator, for example, that created an `Iterator` that calculated the next number instead of trying to store some lookup table. If you're writing framework or interface code where such a "streaming" sort of API might be useful (Guava and its functional classes do a good bit of this), then specifying `Iterable` instead of a collection type might be worth the loss of flexibility on the consumer side.